# CommonCrypto compiled swift 2.3

Tags: swift2

Alguien sabe como puedo usar commonCrypto en swift 2.3, verán baje de git la versión que decía para 2.3 pero cuando quiero importarlo a mi proyecto me dice que fue compilada en 3.0 y no puede usarse, lo extraño es que abro el proyecto de `commonCrypto` y tiene `legacy` habilitado, recompilo y lo importo pero sigue diciendo lo mismo :/

Comment: http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2014/10/03/using-commoncrypto-in-swift/

Comment: Mirate este post, puede servirte de algo

Comment: Muchas gracias ya se la razon, se quedo como pegado el proyecto, tube que generar un proyecto nuevo, y ahi si pudo importar en version 2.3 sin problemas

Answer (score 0):

Esta es la libreria correcta para swift 2.3, version 0.8.3

https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto